# Connect to SQL Server container from C# application

Tags: c#, sql-server, containers, sql-authentication

Have a C# App and SQL Server database from a domain environment; restored the DB in a non-domain support environment (SQL Server running in a Docker Container). Connections are successful via ODBC using SQL Server authentication:

```
Server         10.0.0.1
LoginID        <username of dbOwner>
Password       <password>
Default db     ThisProject
```

The C# App, however, always returns "Login failed: The login is from an untrusted domain" with every variation of a normal connect string:

```
data source=10.0.0.1;
initial catalog=ThisProject;
integrated security=False; 
User Id=<dbOsner>;
Password=<password>;
Trusted_Connection=False;
```

How does one configure the connect string so that the C# App connects with SQL Server authentication?

```
TIA!
```

Tested with variations:

```
integrated security=False, True, SSPI, <missing>;
trusted_Connection=False, True;
```

Comment: Pick any (appropriate) of: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ ?

Comment: Are the credentials you are using for a SQL Server account or a domain account? If it is a domain account, it won't work if the SQL Server isn't joined to the domain.

Comment: Yes, .. tried connectionstrings.com/sql-server, but no examples for SQL Server authentication and there is no domain server here in the lab.

The dbOwner is a SQL Server user.

Comment: Here is an example of what we use, you would of course need to replace the placeholders with the appropriate values for your server:
`"Server=tcp:10.0.0.1,1433;Initial Catalog=<DBName>;User ID=<username>;Password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=30;"`

Comment: Nice, .. but no difference; connection still refused due to untrusted domain.

We did not build the original App, is there anything else that would force a domain trust outside the connect string?

Comment: If the application is solely using the connection string then I'd suggest removing one of `Integrated Security` or `Trusted_Connection` connection string properties - they are synonyms and having both could be confusing the matter, ref: [SqlConnection Connection String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring). Do you have the source code for the C# app? It could well be using a `ConnectionStringBuilder` class to read the connection string and then override some properties before using the result to connect.

Comment: "is there anything else that would force a domain trust"  Can you check If you have "SQl Server and Windows authentication mode" selected (see picture below this link: [second option]{https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2191/how-to-check-sql-server-authentication-mode-using-t-sql-and-ssms/#:~:text=use%20Windows%20Authentication.-,Check,-Using%20SSMS) )? If that second option is checked, you do not need a domain trust, but a local account (with proper authorization in SQL )

Comment: The server has always been mixed mode, ..

Comment: Finally found a workaround - runas:

runas.exe /netonly /user:<SQL Server user> "<path to build .exe><.exe name>.exe"

Very inelegant, but does appears to survive a rebuild.